# SignalR UserIdentifier is null in OnConnected method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a blazor web assembly app and I want to use SignalR for sending push notification. I could stablished a connection and send notification to all users but I have a problem. I want to store user information when a user connected to the app. In **OnConnected** method I have access to ConnectionId but UserIdentifier is null. I follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2). But nothing happened and it still is null.

This code is in client side to stablish a connection:

```
    public async Task<bool> ConnectToNotificationHub()
    {
        bool isConnected = false;
        string url = $"{_configuration["APIBaseURL"]}/hubs/notificationhub";
        string token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync("user_account");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(url, options =>
                {
                    options.AccessTokenProvider=() => Task.FromResult(token);
                })
                .Build();

            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            isConnected=true;

            hubConnection.Closed+=async (s) =>
            {
                isConnected=false;
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                isConnected=true;
            };

            hubConnection.On<string>("notification", m =>
            {
                _notifications.Add(m);
                OnNotificationRecieved(null, null);
            });
        }

        return isConnected;
    }
```

This is Configure method in api project:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("PMS_API");

        app.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "PMS.WebAPI v1"));
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/hubs/notificationhub");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

This is my hub:

```
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    [Authorize]
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ConnectionId: {Context.ConnectionId} - UserIdentifier: {Context.UserIdentifier}"); // TODO: UserIdentifier is empty
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

This is identity events:

```
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception != null)
                        {
                            throw new AppException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Autentication failed.", context.Exception);
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.AuthenticateFailure != null)
                        {
                            throw new AppException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Autentication failed.", context.AuthenticateFailure);
                        }

                        throw new AppException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "You are unauthorized to access this resource.", null);
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                        var signInManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<User>>();
                        var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

                        if (!claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
                        {
                            context.Fail("No claims were found.");
                        }

                        var securityStampClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(new ClaimsIdentityOptions().SecurityStampClaimType);

                        if (securityStampClaim is null)
                        {
                            context.Fail("No security stamp was found.");
                        }

                        var validatedSecurityStamp = await signInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(context.Principal);

                        if (validatedSecurityStamp is null)
                        {
                            context.Fail("Security stamp is not valid.");
                        }

                        var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

                        if (userIdClaim is null)
                        {
                            context.Fail("User id claim was not found.");
                        }

                        var userId = userIdClaim.Value;
                        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

                        if (user.LastCreatedToken is null)
                        {
                            context.Fail("User not logged in.");
                        }

                        if (user.LastTokenExpireDate is not null && user.LastTokenExpireDate < DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            context.Fail("User last token has expired.");
                        }

                        if (!user.IsActive)
                        {
                            context.Fail("User is not active.");
                        }

                        user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    }
                };
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Put `[Authorize]` on the hub class not the OnConnectedAsync method

Comment: @Brennan I changed the place of [Authorize] attribute, but now when a I try to stablish a connection, the api app stops with an exception thrown in OnChallenge event. I added identity events to question.

Comment: Thank you @Brennan, I found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the issue. Thanks to @Brennen for his comment, I should put the [Authorize] attribute on the hub class. After that I realize that I send a wrong token to server. My **user_account** local storage has additional data and I send it as token. I should send token section.